# View node public OR only to verified/role by choice user

Tags: users

It's possible to set the **permission** to view for a Content type. But how can i let the choice to view to public OR only verified users/role to the user?

Making 2 different **Content types** would be an easy solution, but is not convenient.
Also, **Node Access** is to difficult for users (too many choices). Need just a button or check box to hide or view the node public. If it's hidden for public, it should be visible to registered users.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this with tags. Feel free to add information about doing this with tags:

- Added a taxonomy 'visibility' with 2 tags: *public* and *closed*.
- Added to Contenttype a field with a *selection-list* (so, a user can only choose one).

  - (set it to *requiered* to only have 2 options.)
  - (in my case, i set the *default* to public.)
- Enabled taxonomy-module '*Taxonomy Access Control*'
- go to admin/config/people/taxonomy_access >> anonymous >> choose [edit access rule]

  - (in my case it's admin/config/people/taxonomy_access/role/1/edit)
- Under New >> choose the term 'closed' (or your equivalent like 'not for mother-in-law ;-) ).
- Set everything to D (Deny)
- When Content Access is also on, set grant priority to -1 on the   contenttype-page (admin/structure/types/manage/[contenttype]/access